# How to be more specific when configuring vlans at Openstack Neutron with Juju?

Tags: networking, juju, quantum

I have a Openstack Juno deployment, based on MAAS and Juju charms. Im using neutron networking, with neutron-api, neutron-openvswitch and quantum-gateway charms.

I would like to be using vlan in my virtual networking. At the default neutron configuration there is the following config hardcoded :

> [ml2_type_vlan]
>
> network_vlan_ranges = physnet1:1000:2000

What about if want to use vlan numbers only within range 1000:1200? If i change it manually, everytime i change something in Juju, it is overwritten.

How this should be properly changed? How should be vlan properly setup within Juju charms?